# when uploading file by post httpclient the file is left with wrong marks

Tags: c#, httpclient, put

I am uploading a csv file as follows:

```cs
string token = await GetTokenAsync();
string path = "C://...";

_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Token {token}");

MultipartContent content = new();
content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = $"dtes_acreedor_.csv" };

string contenido = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);
StringContent contentData = new(contenido, Encoding.UTF8, "text/csv");
content.Add(contentData);

HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PutAsync("api/v1/resources/auxiliary-files/", content);
```

But then when downloading the same uploaded file and then opening it, it appears with strange characters:

[csv image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4BA3.png)

that could be happening?
This is the uploaded file:
https://prnt.sc/26frlqt

**Edit:**
I put this too and still the same. It is not solved, the file continues to download badly, I have even uploaded another one that has not been formatted by me before and neither.

```
string contenido = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(name, Encoding.UTF8);
 StringContent contentData = new(contenido, Encoding.UTF8, "text/csv");
```

This is how I create the file:

```
File.WriteAllText(name, csv.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
```

The character thing is the least important thing, the curious and important thing about the question is the 3 rows that it adds to the beginning of the file:
https://prnt.sc/26fu1ai

Comment: The diacritics are apparently not being encoded properly.  I'd start on the server (either by using the debugger or by temporarily saving the file on the server directly) and see if the string looks good there or if it's a problem getting back to the client.

Comment: These "strange characters" are nothing but UTF-8 encoding of Spanish special chars. They display wrong in - let me guess: Excel? I bet they look fine if you try to open that file in OpenOffice. Or if you open a blank workbook in Excel, click Data=>Import=>From Text, and specify UTF-8 as encoding...

Comment: Probably the original file is not utf-8. specify the correct encoding in [File.ReadAllTextAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltextasync?view=net-6.0#system-io-file-readalltextasync(system-string-system-text-encoding-system-threading-cancellationtoken)).

Comment: @LocEngineer The file that I am showing is the same one that I have uploaded, after having uploaded it to the api. The second photo is the body of the first request.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes ok, I'll check the upload. Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes look:                                                                                 
  `string contenido = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(name, Encoding.UTF8);
  StringContent contentData = new(contenido, Encoding.UTF8, "text/csv");`                             
 It is not solved, the file continues to download badly, I have even uploaded another one that has not been formatted by me before and neither.

Comment: If the original files is not encoded in UTF-8, *reading* it as UTF-8 is not going to solve the problem. The encoding must be the same throughout the life of the file, from creation onwards.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the original file: `File.WriteAllText(name, csv.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);`

Comment: That should be [edit]ed into the question, as part of a [mre]. We don't know what you haven't written down. For instance, what's `csv` in that context? Does its `ToString` override output UTF-8? Also look at @LocEngineer's comment again. Excel has a hard time with CSV documents in UTF-8 with diacritics. You may need to save in a different encoding or format if you are expecting it to be opened in Excel.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok now you can read. have any solutions?

Comment: You should really read [ask], and the [meta-tag:faq]s, where it's been noted that screenshots of text are no substitute for the actual text in questions. Search engines won't index the text in the image in the page linked to in the question text along with the question, so if someone is searching for something in those extra lines of text, your question (and any answers it might attract) will not be found.... In any case, those lines appear to be the boundary and content-type headers from an HTTP message with an enctype of "multipart/form-data".

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, "appear to be the boundary and content-type headers from an HTTP message with an enctype of "multipart/form-data".  I know that, and if you read my question again?

Comment: Your question has no mention of boundaries or enctypes. You started the question asking about strange characters, which points to an encoding issue. You then edited the question to include something about "the first three rows of the file" followed by a link to a picture of text. I have no idea why those are showing up in the file, because you have not provided the code. Stack Overflow is not here to serve you. It is here to create a knowledge base of high quality questions and answers that help everyone with the same question, for all time.